# Error "initializer element is not constant" when allocate the memory

Tags: c

```
  1 #include<stdio.h>
  2 #include<malloc.h>
  3 
  4 typedef struct node_t{
  5     int i;
  6     struct node_t* link;
  7 }node;
  8 
  9 node* head = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
 10 
 11 if(head == NULL){
 12     printf("\n malloc for head node failed! \n");
 13 }
 14 
 15 int main(){
 16     int i = 10;
 17     node* temp = NULL;
 18     temp = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
 19     if(temp == NULL){
 20         printf("\n malloc for temp node failed! \n");
 21     }
 22     else{
 23         while(i<=10){
 24             ;
 25         }
 26     }
 27     return 0;
 28 }
```

compilation error:

```
linked.c:9:1: error: initializer element is not constant
linked.c:11:1: error: expected identifier or â€˜(â€™ before â€˜ifâ€™
```

I'm trying a simple linked list programme. It's not fully completed. I'm getting a compilation error. Couldn't understand why this happened.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Since you're defining `head` as a global, its initializer needs to be a constant--basically, the compiler/linker should be able to allocate space for it in the executable, write the initializer into the space, and be done. There's no provision for calling `malloc` as you've done above during initialization--you'll need to do that inside of `main` (or something you call from `main`).

```
#include <stdlib.h>

void init() { 
    head = malloc(sizeof(node));
}

int main() { 
    init();
    // ...
}
```

In this case, the code you have in `main` never actually uses `head` though, so you may be able to skip all of the above without a problem.

Answer (score 12):

```
 9  node* head = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
 10 
 11 if(head == NULL){
 12     printf("\n malloc for head node failed! \n");
 13 }
```

These lines are not possible outside the `main()` because any function call or executable should be inside the `main()` function or any function called from main.

For `linked.c:9:1: error: initializer element is not constant`

Only function definitions or any global initialization is possible outside `main()` but initializer must be [constant expression](http://h30097.www3.hp.com/docs/base_doc/DOCUMENTATION/V40F_HTML/AQTLTBTE/DOCU_066.HTM)`.

You can declare the `head` as global but initialization is wrong.

Do it like this :

```
node * head =NULL // here initialization using constant expression


void function () // any function 
{
 head = malloc(sizeof(node));
}
```

For `linked.c:11:1: error: expected identifier`,

`if` statement cannot be outside any function.
In your case , put these lines inside main and problem solved

Answer (score 3):

`head` is a global varibale. Global and static varibales must be initialized by constant expressions, i.e. literals. so you can't do

```
node* head = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use malloc() in global scope. 
   or
you can do like follow

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<malloc.h>
  :
node* head
  :
  :
int main(){
  :
  :
head = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
  :
  :
}
```

Comment: it's better to include `<stdlib.h>` rather `<malloc.h>`